# Outer join the output of two select statement - mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join, outer-join

I am trying to join the output of two select statement, since each select statement will return 0 or 1 output, INNER JOIN will return nothing in case of one returning 0 output.
I was wondering how OUTER join can be done.
I have seen solution for INNER JOIN and have got that one to work but, when I change it to OUTER JOIN I get this error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN (SELECT `value` FROM server_setting WHERE server_id=1 AND server_sett' at line 3

here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT `value` AS url FROM server_setting WHERE server_id=1 AND server_setting_type_id=(SELECT min(id) FROM server_setting_type WHERE type='url')) AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT `value` AS port FROM server_setting WHERE server_id=1 AND server_setting_type_id=(SELECT min(id) FROM server_setting_type WHERE type='port')) AS t2
;
```

sample input:

server_setting table:

```
|---------|----------------------|-----|
|server_id|server_setting_type_id|value|
|---------|----------------------|-----|
|1        |1                     |http |
|1        |2                     |22   |
|---------|----------------------|-----|
```

server_setting_type table:

```
|--|----|
|id|type|
|--|----|
|1 |url |
|2 |port|
|--|----|
```

Result:

```
|----|----|
|url |port|
|----|----|
|http|22  |
|----|----|
```

thanks

Comment: What type of outer join? left, right, full?  consider using `Full Outer join` or `left outer join` or `right outer join`

Comment: Do you want to append the results from both queries? In that case replace the `OUTER JOIN` in your query above with `UNION`. As your query stands right now, if you got it working it would have one row with two columns named `value`. If you don't want to append results could you add sample data and expected results to your question?

Comment: I want to do FULL OUTER JOIN, with FULL added I get the same error.

Comment: @EdGibbs actually I want to show the two resulting columns next to each other, as you mentioned, one row with two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT `value` AS url
      FROM server_setting
      WHERE server_id=1 AND
            server_setting_type_id=(SELECT min(id)
                                    FROM server_setting_type
                                    WHERE type='url')
     ) AS t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT `value` AS port
      FROM server_setting
      WHERE server_id=1 AND
            server_setting_type_id=(SELECT min(id)
                                    FROM server_setting_type
                                    WHERE type='port')
    ) AS t2;
```

Several things.  First, MySQL does not support `full outer join` (which is where you are getting your error.  Second, you don't have an `on` clause.  Third, it seems really strange that the `server_setting_type` table would have multiple rows for "port" and "url".  My first suggestion would be do do a `cross join` instead of a `full outer join`.  That may do what you want.

However, for some reason, I think the following may come closer to what you really want:

```
      SELECT sst_url.value as url, sst_port.`value` AS port
      FROM server_setting ss left outer join
           server_setting_type sst_url
           on ss.server_setting_type_id = sst_port.id and
              sst.type = 'url' left outer join
           server_setting_type sst_port
           on ss.server_setting_type_id = sst_port.id and
              sst.type = 'port'
      where ss.server_id = 1;
```

This version *does* assume that there is only one `id` in `server_setting_type` for "url" and one for "port".  That seems reasonable to me.